# Hegel on Antigone

Tags: greek-language, sophocles, georg-wilhelm-friedrich-hegel, antigone-sophocles

According to [this article](http://mason.gmu.edu/~lsmithg/ahegel.htm):

> According to Hegel's account of Greek tragedy, the conflict is not between good and evil but between goods that are each making too exclusive a claim.

What is Hegel's interpretation of the play *Antigone* written by Sophocles?
Does he say that the crisis in the play can be attributed to a clash between good and good instead of good and evil? If yes then what does he mean by being good?

Comment: So all we need to do to answer this question is read Hegel's [*Vorlesungen über die Ästhetik*](http://www.textlog.de/6011.html)?

Comment: I would revert to George Steiner's book *Antigone* for some of the deepest and far reaching thoughts about this.